# Referencing an arrayLen in structure Coldfusion

Tags: arrays, variables, coldfusion, structure, variable-length-array

How do I reference an `arrayLen`? The code is returning an error saying the  variable is not set when I clearly set it in the beginning of the structure? Do I have to specify something for the key?

```
<cfset structure1 ={
    name = ["john","mary","sue","joe","bob"],
    prodID = ["94","62","24","48","64"],
    skuID = ["020402","024040","101010","780080","232332"],
    distCost = ["34.99","44.99","54.99","64.99","19,99"],
    retailCost = ["50","60","70","90","30"],
    bv = ["4","5","6","7","8"],
    cnt = [#arrayLen(name)#]}
    />
```

Comment: *an error saying the variable is not set when I clearly set it in the beginning of the structure* That is all evaluated as one statement. You cannot reference a variable in the same statement you are defining it.

Comment: What @Leigh said, and you shouldn't need to define the count within the structure anyway. You can always get that by referencing the structure later. `arrayLen(structure1.name)`

Comment: All this looks like data that should have come out of a query. I would be looking for `recordcount`